# Провайдинг зависимостей "перепрыгивая" через компонент

Tags: java, android, dagger2

Имеется три пакета: `a`, `b` и `c`. Каждый из этих пакетов включает в себя интерфейс с буквой, реализацию интерфейса, компонент, модуль и `Scope` (не знаю, как правильно переводится). В результате, выходит вот такая структура проекта:

```
│   
│
├───a   A.java
│       AComponent.java
│       AImpl.java
│       AModule.java
│       AScope.java
│
├───b   B.java
│       BComponent.java
│       BImpl.java
│       BModule.java
│       BScope.java
│
└───c   C.java
        CComponent.java
        CImpl.java
        CModule.java
        CScope.java

Application.java
```

`CComponent` имеет зависимость (dependencies) на `BComponent`, а `BComponent` - на `CComponent`.

`BModule` требует класс `A` для создания класса `B`, а `CModule` требует классы `A` и `B` для создания класса `C`:

```
@AScope
@Component(modules = AModule.class)
public interface AComponent {
    A a();
}

@Module
public class AModule {
    @Provides
    @AScope
    public A provideA() {
        return new AImpl();
    }
}



@BScope
@Component(modules = BModule.class, dependencies = AComponent.class)
public interface BComponent {
    B b();
}

@Module
public class BModule {
    @Provides
    @BScope
    public B provideB(A a) {
        return new BImpl(a);
    }
}



@CScope
@Component(modules = CModule.class, dependencies = BComponent.class)
public interface CComponent {
    C c();
}


@Module
public class CModule {
    @Provides
    @CScope
    public C provideC(A a, B b) {
        return new CImpl(b, a);
    }
}
```

---

При попытке собрать проект, Dagger 2 начинает ругаться, что `CComponent` не может найти провайдера класса `A`:

```
Error:(9, 7) java: com.dugin.rostislav.a.A cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
      com.dugin.rostislav.a.A is injected at
          com.dugin.rostislav.c.CModule.provideC(a, …)
      com.dugin.rostislav.c.C is provided at
          com.dugin.rostislav.c.CComponent.c()
```

---

Почему компонент не может получить доступ к Provide-методам модулей компонентов, который находятся ниже по иерархической цепочке зависимостей (более одного компонента)?

Comment: Не на правах рекламы Жени - https://habrahabr.ru/post/279641/. Советую, там объясняется решение вашей проблемы. Советую к прочтению, если вдруг не до конца поняли основной ответа @Rostislav Dugin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Проблема была в том, что компонент `BComponent` должен был **явно** указать компонентам, имеющим на него зависимости, какие реализации он может провайдить из нижестоящих компонентов. То есть он должен указать, что может дать класс `A`:

```
@BScope
@Component(modules = BModule.class, dependencies = AComponent.class)
public interface BComponent {
    A a();
    B b();
}
```

Для того, чтобы пробрасывать зависимости неявно — можно использовать `Subcomponent`.

---

Очень хорошая статья на хабре про `Component Dependencies` и `Subcomponents`, где раскрывается данный вопрос - [Dagger 2. Часть вторая. Custom scopes, Component dependencies, Subcomponents](https://habrahabr.ru/post/279641/).